# Detect multiple dashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate Usernames with the following rules via `RegExp`:

1. Avoid leading and following dashes
2. Avoid multiple dashes
3. Update: It should allows only `[a-z0-9-]` also.

So a username like `-username`, `username-` or `user---name` they should be all invalid, while a username like `user-name` or `my-user-name` should be still recognized as a valid username.

Currently I'm doing that via two RegExp like this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv7ma/)

```
var a = new RegExp("^([^-][a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9][^-])$", "i");
var b = new RegExp("-[-]+", "i");
var username = "some-one";

if ( a.test(username) && !b.test(username) ) {
    alert(username.match(a)[1]);
} else {
    alert('error');
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine, however I'm wondering if there is any way to combine these two RegExp in one. The reason is not neither performance nor cleaner code. I just want to improve my RegEx-ing skills as I've tried whatever I knew within the past few days, but with no success.

**Update**

Actually this `^([^-][a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9][^-])$` should be this `^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9])$`. I don't know why I put them there! [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv7ma/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/Vv7ma/1/

```
var a = new RegExp("(^-|[-]{2}|-$)", "i");
var username = "some-one";

if (! a.test(username)) {
    alert(username);
} else {
    alert('error');
}
```

If '-' in front, error.

If '-' in end, error.

If '-' more than two in a row, error.

Final answer on http://jsfiddle.net/Vv7ma/3/ which fulfill (It should allows only [a-z0-9-] also.)

```
var a = new RegExp("^([a-z0-9]+-)+[a-z0-9]+$", "i");
var username = "some-one";

if (a.test(username)) {
    alert(username);
} else {
    alert('error');
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me where would you put the `[a-z0-9]` also? Just to get only alphanumeric.

Comment: (^-|[-]{2}|-$) detect invalid string. But something like "!some-one" is valid.

Comment: Slight improvement of Tom's suggestion: `RegExp("(?:^-|-{2}|-$)")`

Comment: @TomChung Tom, the regex won't work for strings without `-` -- I forgot to mention it in the OP, so I just edited like this: `^([a-z0-9]+-?)+[a-z0-9]+$`. Here is the updated fiddle as well -- just in the case someone wanted to use it later: http://jsfiddle.net/Vv7ma/4/